# When to use new.instancemethod vs assigning a method to a class

Tags: python, swig

In our codebase there is Python and C++ married by SWIG. The C++ classes are sometimes given Python extensions like so:

```
%pythoncode %{

def DiscreteKey_baseData(self, baseData):
    pass

def DiscreteKey_asSet(self):
    pass

DiscreteKey.baseData = new_instancemethod(DiscreteKey_baseData, None, DiscreteKey)
DiscreteKey.asSet = new_instancemethod(DiscreteKey_asSet, None, DiscreteKey)

%}
```

or

```
%pythoncode %{

def ParmID_hash(parmID):
    return hash(str(parmID))

ParmID.__hash__ = ParmID_hash

%}
```

What is the difference between using [new.instancemethod](http://docs.python.org/library/new.html) to attach a method to a class, vs. simply assigning it, as in the second example? Could the first example be changed to simply

```
DiscreteKey.baseData = DiscreteKey_baseData
DiscreteKey.asSet = DiscreteKey_asSet
```

? (note that `baseData` takes another argument)

Or is the second example actually deficient in some way, and should be using `new_instancemethod` too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning a function to a class attribute, and doing the same via `new_instancemethod()` (which I assume is a Swig alias for the method constructor, e.g. `types.MethodType`) are exactly equivalent. You can tell by checking `type(DiscreteKey.baseData)`. Regardless of how the method was assigned, it will be `<type 'instancemethod'>`.

The `new_instancemethod()` constructor is useful when assigning functions onto instances, however. This won't work without the method "wrapper."